# Is there a reliable method to guarantee a while loop will execute at a specified frequency in C++?

Tags: c++, while-loop, frequency

I have a while loop that executes a program, with a sleep every so often. The while loop is meant to simulate a real-time program that executes at a certain frequency. The current logic calcualtes a number of cycles to execute per sleep to achieve a desired frequency. This has proven to be innacurate. I think a timer would be a better implementation, but do to the complexity of refactor I am trying to maintain a while loop solution to achieve this. I am looking for advice on a scheme that may more tightly achieve a desired frequency of execution in a while loop. Pseudo-code below:

```
MaxCounts = DELAY_TIME_SEC/DESIRED_FREQUENCY;

DoProgram();

while(running)
{
  if(counts > MaxCounts)
  {
    Sleep(DELAY_TIME_SEC);
  }
}
```

Comment: How accurate does it need to be?

Comment: This loop is good for an operation that needs to execute about once-a-minute or so.

Comment: Most common OSs (MS-Windows, Linux etc) are not real-time OSs.  They do not guarantee that a thread will not be pre-empted or scheduled for a specific time-slice.  It all depends on how accurate you want frequency to be and if you want to program around jitters etc.  Have a read of [Fix Your Timestep!](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/) it may offer you some solutions.

Comment: The frequency I am trying to replicate is 250uS i.e. 4 calls per millisecond. I know this may not be super feasible, but I just wanted to look into some possible options

Comment: @GodJohnson Measure how long the last call took. and then sleep for 250uS minus how long it took. For Linux you can just call usleep or nanosleep. For Windows... not sure.

Comment: I guess that Linux also can't sleep that short. If you are okay with using 100% CPU time, then you can implement busy-wait sleep by measuring the time over and over until it's time to stop sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reliably schedule an operation to occur at specific times on a non-realtime OS.

As C++ runs on non-realtime OS's, it cannot provide what cannot be provided.

The amount of error you are willing to accept, in both typical and extreme cases, will matter. If you want something running every minute or so, and you don't want drift on the level of days, you can just set up a starting time, then do math to determine when the nth event should happen.

Then do a wait for the nth time.

This fixes "cumulative drift" issues, so over 24 hours you get 1440+/-1 events with 1 minute between them.  The time between the events will vary and not be 60 seconds exactly, but over the day it will work out.

If your issue is time on the ms level, and you are ok with a loaded system sometimes screwing up, you can sleep and aim for a time before the next event shy half a second (or whatever margin makes it reliable enough for you).  Then busy-wait until the time occurs.  You may also have to tweak process/thread priority; be careful, this can easily break things badly if you make priority too high.

Combining the two can work as well.